# Division of two properties in Logstash Aggregate filter gives only 0 or 1 while I need value with 2 digit precision

Tags: logstash, aggregate

I am calculating ratio for every new record processed by aggregate in Logstash as below :
map['work_order_counts']['trades'].find {|t| t['name'] == event.get('primarytrade')}['trade_work_order_ratio_past_36'] = map['work_order_counts']['trades'].find {|t| t['name'] == event.get('primarytrade')}['trade_total_work_orders_past_36'] / map['work_order_counts']['total_work_orders_past_36']

I am getting ratio as 0 or 1 but I am looking for more accurate value like 2 or 3 digit decimal i.e. 74/77 = 0.961 but instead I am getting 1.

I tried trade_work_order_ratio_past_36 as type float and scaled_float.
trade_total_work_orders_past_36 and total_work_orders_past_36 are of type long in my mapping.

```
 "trade_total_work_orders_past_36": {
   "type": "long"
 },
 "trade_work_order_ratio_past_36": {
   "type": "scaled_float"
 },
 "total_work_orders_past_36": {
  "type": "long"
 }
```

Is there anything I am missing or any other type I should use ?

Comment: Are you sure the map entries are floats before you calculate the ratio? Perhaps use .to_f either whilst adding the entries or when calculating the ratio.

Comment: My entries are integers like as I mentioned 74/77.  I can try .to_f while calculating ratio. May be something like this?? : map['work_order_counts']['trades'].find {|t| t['name'] == event.get('primarytrade')}['trade_work_order_ratio_past_36'] = (map['work_order_counts']['trades'].find {|t| t['name'] == event.get('primarytrade')}['trade_total_work_orders_past_36'] / map['work_order_counts']['total_work_orders_past_36']).to_f

Comment: If they are integers then 74/77 would be 0, 77/77 would be 1. Just adding .to f at the end will get you 0.0 and 1.0 for those. You need to use .to_f on both the 74 and the 77, then you will get the ratio as a float by default.

Comment: yes, I just hardcoded the value to test and  (74/77).to_f returns 0.0. But I want value as 0.96 or 0.961  when 74 is divided by 77. Let me try to use .to_f on both values.

Comment: Thank you @Badger. I am getting ratio as float by applying .to_f on both properties. Is there a way to restrict the precision upto 2 or 3 digits? I am getting 0.03896103896103896 when 3 is divided by 77 which is unnecessary and more complex to handle.

Comment: You could use .round(2) or .round(3) on the resulting Float